# page with live calculations from backend

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

I have web application with textboxes, selectboxes, chackboxes, submit button and labels showing live calculation made by backend. Currently textboxes sends  their value to backend on event BLUR. But the problem is that when cursor is in textbox, operator has to enter SUBMIT button twice (one to leave textbox, second for submiting data).

Is there any design pattern for such use? how to do it better?

Comment: A single submit should be sufficient but if you want help, it's a good idea to include your code in the post.

Comment: thanks for answer. this is rather design problem. The idea is that first click cause leaving the text box only, so the second click is needed.